# How to Insert html, special charters to a sql database with PDO?

Tags: php, html, database, pdo, mysqli

I'm trying to insert some html special characters inside my MySql MyIsam table

***Used query :***

```
INSERT INTO place_menu (menu_ref_place, menu_name, menu_price, menu_card_price, menu_full_price, menu_desc) VALUES ('1', 'SUPPLÌ CASERECCI x3', '', '', '', 'asdasd')
```

***Returned error :***

```
 SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation
```

***Note :***

This request work perfectly with mysqli but with pdo the insert is truncated to `SUPPLÌ`

Anther problem is where I insert html tags and quotes, for example if i try to insert this string "$%&\'12\'12\'3\'12\'3123" I get nothing at all...just blank space :/

***Another debug info :***

```
 INSERT INTO place_menu (menu_ref_place, menu_name, menu_price, menu_card_price, menu_full_price, menu_desc) VALUES ('1', 'adasd'asdasd', '2', '3.80', '400', 'asdasda sasdasda s0d8aèsdaysd8sd8asdèa0sd8yè0=?£!(/\"=)(!?)(\"?!)\"')
    Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'asdasd', '2', '3.80', '400', '<b>asdasda s</b>asdasda s0d8a?sdaysd8sd8asd?a0sd8y' at line 1' in /home/contat13/public_html/app/menu/app/inc/db.cl.php:36 Stack trace: #0 /home/contat13/public_html/app/menu/app/inc/db.cl.php(36): PDO->query('INSERT INTO pla...') 
#1 /home/contat13/public_html/app/menu/app/inc/db.cl.php(146): DB->sql_query('INSERT INTO pla...') 
#2 /home/contat13/public_html/app/menu/insert_dish.php(15): DB->insert('place_menu', Array, false) 
#3 {main} thrown in /home/contat13/public_html/app/menu/app/inc/db.cl.php on line 36
```

***Used php class :***

Comment: Show what you're using for making the INSERT queries.

Comment: I tried both prepend() and query() ...currently its a Class http://jsfiddle.net/StartStep/tj4gvy7f/ here the class

Comment: You appear to have answered a question nobody asked. Please provide the code. and possibly the class being used.

Comment: Done :) Class added to jsfiddle

Comment: Why are you using jsfiddle for PHP code? It's for HTML and Javascript.

Comment: Post your PHP code here.

Comment: You want to be calling `insert()` with the "secure" flag, I.e. passing true instead of false and then fix if necessary. Tbh, I don't really see the point in the class at all.

Comment: the problem is not the CLASS i tried with normal charters and worked like a charm in both cases :)

Comment: The problem is with PDO maybe...

Comment: drop that useless class and use PDO directly...

Answer (score 0):

The problem with HTML. I have discovered that the form were not UTF-8 encoded.
The solutions is to check same encoding on:

```
1) the page/form
2) table and column (if any) charset (not collation) 
3) db connection.
```

All 3 of them must have utf-8 encoding.